Facing "dot net is not recognized as an internal" on windows server
I am working on to upgrade .NET framework for a project (upgrading from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 8)

For upgrading framework, I need to work on my local machine where all required .net SDKs are installed.
Post upgrading the framework in project, I will need to publish code on windows server.
I am trying to find out which is the current .NET runtime (not SDK) installed on windows server on which I will need to publish code.
While doing that, I am facing this problem.

Note that the application is already running on the server with old framework. But I am not sure how to know if I the application will work or not after I publish code after upgrading framework of the project.
How can we know which exactly .net runtime framework is installed in windows server and how and which .NET runtime framework will support application with .NET 8 framework?
